# Hibernate ManyToMany join

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and I am using it with Spring. I have the following tables:

```
@Entity
@Configurable
public class Location {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long locationid;

    private String locationName;

    @ManyToOne
    private Site site;

//getters setters skipped
}

@Entity
@Configurable
public class Site {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long siteid;

    private String siteName;

    @ManyToOne
    private Country country;
    //getters setters skipped
    }

@Entity
@Configurable
public class Country {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long countryid;

    private String countryName;
    @ManyToOne
    private Region region;
    //getters setters skipped
}

@Entity
@Configurable
public class Region {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long regionid;

    private String regionName;
    //getters setters skipped
}

public class Assets {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long assetId;


    @ManyToOne
    private Location location;
    //getters setters skipped
}
```

I want to pull all assets based on Regions. How should I do that?

How do I use the relationship between Region --> Country --> Site --> Location and pull the relevant records? How do I do it without affecting the performance?

Or should I just redesign the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just complete it by a @NamedQuery in the class Assets :
 `select a from Asserts a where a.location.site.contry.regin.reginName = :reginName`

Hope help.